# Partial viewmodel in Prism

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, viewmodel, prism, partial

I'm trying out Prism for WP 8.1 Runtime (Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Mvvm.Store). Is there any way to implement partial viewmodel? For example, I would like to implement different VM for each item in Pivot control.

P.S. This can be done in Caliburn.Micro using Conductor class.

Comment: Why not have x sub-viewmodels as properties in your main viewmodel? Don't abuse partial classes for code separation.

Comment: My primary goal is to enable lazy loading - not just code separation.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could do Lazy/AsnycLazy where T is your sub-viewmodel. Then just bind the selected page, and load the subVMs when required. Currently PRISM doesn't offer any built-in solutions for this.

Comment: Please, can you clarify your answer?